# How to share a file on bluetooth with Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth

I want to share an image file from an Ubuntu phone. I opened the "Gallery" application, then I opened a picture, clicked on the menu and chose "Share". I got a screen to choose from 5 apps: Facebook, Messaging, Tagger, Dekko and Telegram. That's it. Bluetooth is enabled and the other device is paired.

Is sharing via bluetooth not implemented yet? Or am I not looking in the right place?

Comment: Bluetooth doesn't work on the Ubuntu phone. You can pair a device (but the connection gets constantly dropped) but that is about it, you can neither view files nor send files, nor can it receive files. Hopefully this will be fixed in a later update.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Click on the Dash home and type Personal File Sharing.
Check the box that says Receive files in Downloads folder over Bluetooth
If you have paired your device with the computer already, then choose Only for set up devices under Accept files, else choose Always (this is not preferred as pretty much anyone in your blue tooth's range could send you files)
Click close and you're done!

Comment: -1 This answer is also not applicable on the Ubuntu phone